# Symfony/Doctrine : Filter query by child attribute

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to execute a query to obtain all the `Repos` from an specific `Organization`, but it returns an empty result... (I have data in the DB!)
Repos and Organization are a `Many to Many` relation.

Here's the `Repos` Entity:

```
/**
 * Repos
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="repos")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ReposRepository")
 */
 class Repos
 {

     ...

     /**
      * 
      * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Organization", inversedBy="repos")
      *
      */
     protected $orgs;

     ...
```

Here's the `Organization` Entity:

```
 /**
  * Organization
  *
  * @ORM\Table(name="organization")
  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository
  * \organizationRepository")
  */
  class Organization
  {
      ...

      /**
       *
       * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Repos", mappedBy="orgs")
       *
       */
       protected $repos;

      ...
  }
```

Here's the `Repository` with the `QueryBuilder`:

```
/**
 * ReposRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
 class ReposRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
 {

    public function findReposByName($name){
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');

        // Build query
        $qb->select('r')
           ->andWhere(
                ':searchName MEMBER OF r.orgs'
             );
        $qb->setParameter('searchName',$name);
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }

 }
```

The `$name` is the name of an Organization and I want to obtain all the Repos with the the same organization name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter with the `name` attribute of your Organization, you have to do a join query.

## With the query builder

```
public function findReposByName($name){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');
    $qb->select('r')
       ->join('r.orgs', 'o')
       ->where('o.name = :searchName')
       ->setParameter('searchName', $name);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

## In DQL

```
public function findReposByName($name){
    $dql =<<<EOF
        SELECT r
        FROM AppBundle:Repos r
        INNER JOIN r.orgs o
        WHERE o.name = :searchName
EOF;
    return $this->_em
                ->createQuery($dql)
                ->setParameter('searchName',$name)
                ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: WOWW, it works!! I saw the solution some days ago, but I put the same join's alias as the CreateQueryBuilder! That's why it didn't work! Thank you!